# middleware return error express-Validator is not a function

Tags: javascript, express-validator

so I am using app.use(expressValidator()); as a middle ware, when I lunch my server I get the an error message saying "TypeError: expressValidator is not a function"
I remember using the same code in the past without any problem, I think the V6 may have changed something. any idea?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

By expressValidator did you mean https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator ?

If that so, you could use it like this

```js
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

here is the link to the documentation https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Comment: The problem is that I am only having issue when using it as a middle ware using app.use(expressValidator());

Comment: Where did you get `expressValidator` function? As far as i know express-validator only export these middeware, see https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/blob/master/src/index.ts

Comment: from expressValidator = require(express-Validator);